# Split date range to smaller ranges

Tags: python

I would like to split a date range to smaller date ranges. The function should take start date, end date and number of slices and returns a start date and end date tuple list.

If i pass (2019-04-01, 2019-04-22, 5) it should return:

```
(2019-04-18, 2019-04-22)
(2019-04-13, 2019-04-17)
(2019-04-08, 2019-04-12)
(2019-04-03, 2019-04-07)
(2019-04-01, 2019-04-02)
```

This is what i have now:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def split_date_range(start_date, end_date, num_of_slices):

    interval =(end_date - start_date).days / num_of_slices

    for i in range(num_of_slices):

        partition_start_date = max(start_date, end_date - timedelta(days=(i + 1) * interval + i))
        partition_end_date = partition_start_date + timedelta(days=interval)
        yield (partition_start_date, partition_end_date)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=22)
    end_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    print(list(split_date_range(start_date, end_date, 5)))
```

The logic behind this is the difference between 2019-04-01 and 2019-04-22 is 22 days. If i use 22 divide by 5 round up to 5 (4.4). Each tuple date range is 5 days and leaving the rest of the days as the last item in the tuple list. What is neatest way to implement this?

Comment: I would go with the `datetime` module. Did you try using it?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and describe exactly which step you got stuck on? SO isn't really a code writing service.

Comment: This would probably be a good place to start [Iterate over chunks of date range](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127124/iterate-over-chunks-of-date-range). Instead of using `span_days` find your time delta between the dates and divide by the number of ranges you want.

Comment: Added my code. wondering what's a better and neater way to do this.

Comment: What you have seems fine enough to me.

Comment: You may want to check out [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for questions about improving working code.